# Convert large number of lists into variables in a data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a couple hundred lists of length ~4000 that I want to combine into a data frame with each list becoming a variable in the data frame.  How can I do this while preserving the names of the lists as the variable names in the new data frame?

Here is what I have so far with the first 3 lists (formtype, cl, and date)

```
datalist = list()

datalist[[1]] <- formtype
datalist[[2]] <- cl
datalist[[3]] <- date


data.out = as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,datalist))
```

However, this does not preserve the list names (formtype,cl,date,etc...) as variable names in data.out

Comment: `as.data.frame(datalist)`?

Comment: I got the following error when I tried that: Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = 
    TRUE,  : 
      arguments imply differing number of rows: 1231, 1110, 1227

Comment: If the items in the list are of different lengths, they cannot be combined into the columns of a single data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `formtype`, `cl` and `date` are ordinary vectors (not lists) and that they are in the global environment, i.e. in workspace, then:

```
formtype <- cl <- date <- 1:3  # test data
Names <- c("formtype", "cl", "date")
as.data.frame(mget(Names, .GlobalEnv))
```

giving:

```
  formtype cl date
1        1  1    1
2        2  2    2
3        3  3    3
```

If `formtype`, `cl` and `date` really are lists as shown below then `unlist` each:

```
formtype <- cl <- data <- as.list(1:3) # test data
Names <- c("formtype", "cl", "date")
as.data.frame(lapply(mget(Names, .GlobalEnv), unlist))
```